# Setting points or cues in a video timeline

Tags: iphone

is it possible to do following?

I want to set/save points of time in a video. For this I would need the video time line like you have it in the VideoEditorController view. On the top of my iPhone screen should be the time line, on rest of the screen is the preview picture of my video at the selected time. The user should be able to "go" through this time line by his finger and to see the refreshed preview picture of the selected point of time (like it is usual in video edit programs) in the preview window. The user should be able to swipe through the video and to find the right place in the video. Then, if he did find the right place/scene, he should be able to push a button and the point of time (timestamp) of this "place" in his/her video should be saved somewhere for later use by the app.

Is this type of video controlling possible and is it possible to add this button for saving the point of time? Or perhaps it will be possible with the next SDK? I didn't find an answer.

Thank you in advance !
Greets

Comment: Everything's possible if you write the code to do it yourself...

Comment: Yes, but I just needed the right direction... luckily I did find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is MPMoviePlayerController... here you can access the property "currentPlaybackTime", which gives you the timestamp in seconds of the position in the movie.